# How can I cause a levitating magnet to rotate?

Tags: electromagnetism, rotation, electric-current, levitation

I have a device like this one:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA_hw_lY-OY (All of them work the same)

Here's an image:
[image]

I want to make it spin without touching it with hands.

I tried using magnets of several kinds, and tried to put them in many places around it but it didn't make it spin. It just made it to vibrate a little.

I guess there is a point in which the "pen" will spin and spin. Basically, I prefer to make it rotate not with magnets, but with an electric current. Most likely, I will use an AC generator, and it also makes sense, because I thought that in some point there will be same poles, and then the pen will spin a little bit, and then there will be different poles, but the alternate current changes the poles each time, so the poles will always be the same.

My question is: in what point should it happen?

Comment: Maybe you could add a bar magnet inside the pen, across it's width and put two windings in the base to construct a two-phase [AC synchronous motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_motor#Three-phase_AC_synchronous_motors)?

Comment: You could use magnets instead of hands to give it the angular momentum it needs for a spin, This should be similar to the small twist by hand in the video, a fast pass.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I found a solution that seems to work very well.
I took a computer fan, and put it on the edge of the pen. Then I had put two magnets on the fan, and used a `Stirrer`. It spins quite alright.
Also, if you don't put the magnets, and blow air on the fan, it spins really fast.

Answer (score 1):

Using electromagnetic flux to generate enough momentum to cause "spinning" or speeds of greater then 20 rotations per minute, can be accomplished easily using rotating fans or other objects that act as a base and move independently of the surrounding mass. but hypothetically lets say that we desire the pen to move independently of the base or the 'levitating magnetic base' then I have a few hypothesises.

1. have the pen contain a different level of magnetic material located at alternate ends, then using the opposite pole connected to a rotating object that is within range to cause the vibration of the pen
2. Think of the pen as being earth. having two alternate poles that "spin" and levitate around the electromagnetic viabilities given from our sun, the center. So the pen would need alternate poles to rotate itself, then a large enough levitating base to circumnavigate. then holding a larger charged and semi-larger charged respectively negative to positive charge magnetic interference from the pens respectively positive to negative charges.
3. talk to an molecular physicist